# Chat window visible even after setting minimized="true"

Tags: facebook, facebook-customer-chat

I am using FB Customer Chat plugin on my site and have set the minized option to true. It was working fine and now all of a sudden the chat window appears by default and I am not able to close the chat window. This is causing my content to be hidden behind the chat window.

Below is the code from my implementation:

```
<div class="fb-customerchat help-page" page_id=<<my-page-id>> minimized="true" logged_in_greeting="Hi! How may I help you today?"
    logged_out_greeting="Thank you">
```

Answer (score 4):

The `minimized` attribute has been deprecated (see [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#customization)). Instead, use the `greeting_dialog_display` attribute (applying `greeting_dialog_display="hide"` to the element should have the same effect as `minimized=true` did prior to deprecation).

Answer (score -2):

remove the "" your attribute
minimized=true